# Variable Buffer?

Tags: c, variables, initialization

I have this code which calculates the exponential power of a value, both of which is entered by the user, example, user enters 2^3 = 8, its suppose to work like this but somethings wrong, the end result is 608, when I debug in the pwra function in the counter, even before the counter initiates the result value is set, from where I dont know because I did not set it so the end result is 608. I feel like its a buffer issue but I have tried fflush both in and out, it doesnt work. So when I copy this code to a new window, it works for sometime, then same again, earlier it was showing 624 as the end result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int pwra (int, int);

int main()
{
   int number, power, xx;
   printf("Enter Number: ");
   scanf("%i", &number);

   printf("Enter Number: ");
   scanf("%i", &power);

   xx=pwra (number,power);
   printf("Result: %i", xx);

   return 0;
}

int pwra (int num, int pwr)
{
   int count, result;

   for(count=1;count<=pwr;count++)
   {
      result = result*num;
   }
   return result;
}
```

Another thing, how can I calculate the exponential value from a `float`, because when I change all the `int` to `float` the end result is always 0.00000 even with `%lf`.

Comment: As for your floating point problem, besides what Sourav Ghosh answered, are you using `float` or `double`? While it doesn't matter for `printf`, when you use [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) the format specification and type matters: `"%lf"` is for `double` and `"%f"`  is for `float`.

Comment: OK, guys thanks, seems to be a compiler issue in one Software when I change the Software its working fine, anyway after initiating its working in both, however the float thing did not work in either, the end result is still 0.00000. I changed the int to double and float as well, did not work..I did get a -1.NANO as answer but after that nothing, still 0.00000. To clarify what i'm trying to do is to get the user to input both the value and the exponent as floating point, the end result will definitely be long so the end result has to be in long double, as lf..

Comment: Whatever issue you are having, it's not a compiler issue. Sourav Ghosh answered the main question, now if you have problems with floating point numbers you should post another question about it, showing the new code (using floating point data types and formats) and we will gladly help you with that.

Comment: @TryllZ repeat after me: no, it is not an issue with compiler, PEBKAC.

Comment: Definitely will post about the floating. Its Is Not A Compiler Issue, I agree. Thank You folks..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're hitting [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) for the below line

```
 result = result*num;
```

as you've not initialized `result`. The initial value for an uninitialized automatic local variable is indeterminate. Using that invokes UB.

Always initialize your local variables, like

```
 int count = 0 , result = 0 ; //0 is for illustration, use any value, but do use
```

Then coming to the case, where you want to change all `int`s to `float`, only changing the data type of the variable is not sufficient. You need to change the corresponding format specifiers, too.

Comment: In his case, `result` needs to be initialized to 1

Comment: And the `float` behaviour would result from the indeterminate value of `result` happening to be `0.0f`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala You're very right, still an _extra_ initialization wouldn't hurt, either. Saves you many times. :)

Comment: Yeah, that is true especially if the indeterminate value is an "unspecified 0" and you were supposed to initialize to 0.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala and [there you go](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36735865/2173917). :)