# Calculating the result of a power and a base without math.h

Tags: c

At my university I was asked to create a program that asks the user for two inputs. One is the base and the other is the power of a number. I am not allowed to use `math.h` only loops.

This is my code thus far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int base;
    printf(" Please enter the base: ");
    scanf("%d", &base);

    int power;
    printf(" Please enter the power: ");
    scanf("%d", &power);

    printf("\n%d ^ %d is the same as...\n\n", base, power);

    printf(" %d", base);

    int reps;
    int number;
    for(reps = base; reps <= power; reps += 1) {
        printf("* %d ", base);
    }

    for(number; number <= power;number += 1) {
        int result = base * base;
        for (result; number <= power; result = base * result) {
            result = result * base;
            printf("\n or  %d", result);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Please help me. I am so lost and I feel like crying :( not that it matters.

Comment: `int number;` --> `int number = 0;`

Comment: Could you tell us what happens and what is expected to happen?

Comment: Are you a classmate of [this OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36735396/variable-buffer)..lol

Comment: @SouravGhosh better yet `for(number = 0; ...`

Comment: Even better (if on later c standards): `for (int number = 0`

Comment: @LPs s/calls/class/? ;-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Good catch.

Answer (score 4):

(Your main issue is that you are using an uninitialised variable; the behaviour of doing that in C is *undefined*.)

But let's rework the answer. The first thing to do is to separate the actual power *function* from all the input and output. With regards to that function, I'll put my favourite way into the answer pool on the understanding that you'll work through it carefully and understand it.

You can ace this problem using a technique called *exponentiation by squaring*:

```
int getPower(int base, int power/*must be non-negative*/)
{
    int ret = 1;
    while (power){
        if (power & 1){ /*this means the current value of `power` is odd*/
            ret *= base;
        }
        power >>= 1; /*ToDo - figure this out with your debugger*/
        base *= base;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The method is adequately explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: The only sane answer, the others are like advising multiplication by adding in a loop. But the comment `/*this means power is odd*/` isn't really relevant, it's more about examining each bit position.

Comment: @WeatherVane: yes that was misleading. I've amended.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: the algorithm works for negative `base`. (It even works for a floating point `base`).

Answer (score 0):

The loop for calculating the power looks like this

```
int product = 1;
for(int multiplicationCounter = 1;multiplicationCounter <= power; multiplicationCounter ++) {
    product *= base;
}
printf("Result is %d", product);
```

You can integrate this in your code, maybe change the output.
This should replace your whole second for-loop.

Comment: Base as in 10 to the power of 2 = 10 squared. The loop will then loop 2 times as up to *power* and multiply the product each time by base as in 10*10. Or what do you mean?

Comment: I was confused by the phrasing of his question. I thought base referred to the base of the number. For example `11 base 2 = 3 base 10`. I was wrong though.

Comment: Ah sorry. Didn't get you there.

Answer (score 0):

assume both base and power is positive integer,

then

```
int Result =1;
for (int i=0; i<=power;i++)
{
if(power==0)
Result=1;

Result =Result*base;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     int base;
     printf(" Please enter the base: ");
     scanf("%d", &base);

     int power;
     printf(" Please enter the power: ");
     scanf("%d", &power);

     printf("\n%d ^ %d is the same as...\n\n", base, power);

     printf(" %d", base);

     int reps;
     int number;
     int result=1:


        for(number=1; number <= power;number += 1)
        {
            result=result*base
        }

     printf("The result is %d", result);
     return 0;
```

}